# You have a box of cards titled 1-9. You pick 3 cards, without replacement, What's the likelihood of the sum being multiple of 3;4;5? (separately)

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

Multiple of 3;
Multiple of 4;
Multiple of 5;

I tried doing the first option, resulting in 18/504. This was the reasoning:

First: how many ways, given 3 numbers between 1-9, can we add up to 9?

Case 1: all numbers are multiples of 3. [3, 6, 9] is an example of this

Case 2: two numbers are multiples of 3. There is nothing here since 3n+b only equals 3c for some integer c if and only if b is a multiple of 3.

Case 3: one number is a multiple of three. Let’s write out the two number sets that have multiples of 3: [1, 2], [1,5], [1,8], [2,4], [2,7].  There are 3 times as many sets in the problem since adding 3, 6, or 9 doesnt change this being a multiple of three or not

Case 4: no numbers are multiples of three. [1,4,7] and [2,5,8] are examples of this.

There are thus (1) + (0) + 3(5) + 2 sets that lead up to a multiple of 3. There are (9x8x7) total sets.

But i want to know if this is correct, as well as the answers to the other options.
And if possible, how the answers would change if there was replacement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your result is correct.
Also, I don't think this is the simplest explanation, but it is the best I could think of.
You can divide the numbers from 1 to 9 into three types:
A) multiple of three: $3n$ which are $3,6,9$
B) numbers before a multiple of three: $3n-1$ that are $2,5,8$
C) numbers after a multiple of three (let's say that $0$ is a multiple of three, meaning that $0=3\times0$): $3n+1$ that are $1,4,7$

To get another multiple of three from the sum of three of this number you can:

- sum three numbers of the same type (A,B or C), so there are 3 possibilities: $1+4+7=12$, $2+5+8=15$, $3+6+9=18$
- sum one for each type, so there are $3\times3\times3=27$ possibilities

If you try and sum two numbers of the same type and then the third of another, you will find that there is no chance that you will get a multiple of three (as you already pointed out for the numbers which are multiples of three).
We should count the permutation of each case, so we have to multiply the 30 cases by $3!$
So there are $30\times3!=180$ cases -out of a total of 504 - in which the sum of the number you've picked is a multiple of 3.

About the case in which the sum is a multiple of 4, let's find all the cases in which the sum is even:

- if all the numbers are even, and this happens $\binom{4}{3}=4$, that is the number of possible groups of 3 even numbers from the 4 that we can pick (2,4,6,8).
- if two numbers are odd and one is even, and this happens $\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1}=40$, that is the number of possible groups of 1 even number from the 4 and 2 odd number from the 5 (1,3,5,7,9).

This gives us 44 cases in which the sum is a multiple of 2.
In the first case we have that our 3 numbers $a,b,c$ can be written as
$$a=2k \quad b=2i \quad c=2j$$
where $k,i,j$ are numbers between 1 and 4 different from each other. So
$$(a+b+c)=2(k+i+j)$$
Now we need to know if $k+i+j$ is again a multiple of 2; as above this happens when they are all even or when there is one even and two odds. But they can't be 3 even numbers because the only even number they can be are 2 and 4. So two of them are 1 and 3 and the ore can be 2 or 4, so we have only 2 cases in which the sum $a+b+c$ is a multiple of 4.

Now we need to examine the other 40 cases, knowing that
$$a=2k+1 \quad b=2i+1 \quad c=2j \quad a+b+c=2(k+i+j+1)$$
This time $k,i,j$ can be numbers between 0 and 4 and two of them can be equal (for example if $a=3$ and $c=2$ we would have $k=1$ and $j=1$)
We want to know if $k+i+j+1=2\times some\ costant$, which would mean that $k+i+j$ is odd.
This happens when each one is odd, and that covers 2 cases (two 3 and one 1 and two 1 and one 3).
The other circumstance is when two numbers are even and one is odd, and this covers $3\times3\times2=18$ cases.
So finally we have $18+2+2$ cases in which the sum is a multiple of 4; again we have to multiply that number by the possible permutations of each case, so we have $3!\times22=132$ cases out of 504.
For the multiple of 5, I think that it could be easier to count the cases by hand and then multiply for the number of permutations ($3!$).

Comment: Thank you very much! What about the answers for multiples of 4 and 5?

Comment: Wait I realized I'm wrong, I'm editing the answer

Comment: Right! Please notify me when you're done doing so.